# How to call modal dialog box dll?

Tags: visual-c++

VC two modal dialog box programs (EXE). package into A.DLL and B.DLL.

Then, in an EXE, display both modal dialog box DLLs simultaneously.

one:
the aFunc function is called to display A.DLL modal dialog box form;
At this point, the aFunc function will be stuck, Because RunModalLoop message loop;

two:
the bFunc function is called to display B.DLL modal dialog box form;
At this point, the bFunc function will be stuck, Because RunModalLoop message loop;

If you close the A.DLL dialog box, will enter the bFunc function, instead of aFunc function;
an error has occurred.

Is there any way to jump normally?
Close the A.DLL modal dialog box and jump to aFunc;
Close the B.DLL modal dialog box and jump to bFunc;